# Display the next and previous category

Tags: category, params, previous-next

The examples I have seen to link to previous and next entry all seem to be for sections. I want to get the previous and next category.

My category handler is called 'media'.

So I might have entries in this category such as :
Time
Life
People

When viewing the entry 'Life', I want to be able to go back to Time (Previous) or to People (Next). Again, these entries are entries in my category.

I tried:

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('media').relatedTo(category) %}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
{% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
{% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```

That didn't work, so I also tried:

```
{% set category = entry.category.first() %}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('media').order('title asc').relatedTo(category) %}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
{% if nextEntry %}
    {% set nextEntryUrl = nextEntry.url %}
{% else %}
    {% set firstEntry = craft.entries.section('media').first() %}
    {% set nextEntryUrl = firstEntry.url %}
{% endif %}
{% if prevEntry %}
    {% set prevEntryUrl = prevEntry.url %}
{% else %}
    {% set lastEntry = craft.entries.section('media').last() %}
    {% set prevEntryUrl = lastEntry.url %}
{% endif %}
```

But also no good.

Comment: Assuming `category` is a valid CategoryModel, and `entry` belongs to a section with the handle `"media"`, your first example looks legit. In other words, this is pretty much impossible to answer. Maybe share your entire template (as a Github gist, if its big)?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example and description, it's a bit hard to tell whether you are dealing with a `category` template or an `entry` template, because in your description you say that the category handle is called 'media', but in the example you are grabbing entries in the section called 'media'.

Assuming you are on a category template (i.e. trying to create a category index page for example), then you should be able to just grab the current category from the 'category' variable (provided by craft), entries related to that category using `relatedTo(category)`, and the next and previous categories from `category.nextSibling` and `category.previousSibling` (or `category.next` and `category.previous` depending on whether your categories are hierarchical). If so, then the following should work (not tested):

```
{# category template #}

{% set prevCategory = category.prevSibling %}
{% set nextCategory = category.nextSibling %}
{% set entries = craft.entries('mySection').relatedTo(category) %}

<h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
<section class="category-index">
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <article>
            <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
</section>

{% if prevCategory %}<a href="{{ prevCategory.url }}">Previous</a> {% endif %}{% if nextCategory %}<a href="{{ nextCategory.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```

If you are dealing with an entry template (i.e. an entry detail page), then you may need to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: This would be on an entry template. I added your code. It allowed me to go Previous and Next, but it seems like the order was based on the order ID (when I added the category), rather than in alphabetical order. So if we are on category entry "68 Color Micro Journal", the next one should be "68 Micro Journal." http://www.colorcomputergames.com/media

Comment: Categories are reorder-able (and hierarchical) — prevSibling and nextSibling will simply return the previous/next in the order that they are set in.

Comment: If this is an entry template (i.e. as in an entry in a section or channel), then wouldn't you want next/previous to go to the next entry? vs next category? You may need to clarify the original question a bit more.